# Ahoy gem not storing location data in Visit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ahoy

I have the `ahoy_matey` gem installed in my rails `4.2.6`/ruby `2.3.1` application and placed the `ahoy.trackAll();` and the `//= require ahoy` code in my `application.js`.

For some reason, none of the location data is being saved to the Visit. Does anybody have any idea as to why? I could not find anything in the gem's issues.

Comment: look at https://github.com/ankane/ahoy#geocoding

Comment: I tried adding the recommended code but that did not seem to solve the issue. I have this exact same set-up in another application and everything is working properly. For some reason this one is not.

Comment: Where you able to figure this problem out?

Comment: I faced the same issue and here is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77256288/16917889

Answer (score 0):

## Disclaimer

I ran into the same issue with my application several months ago. I know this question was asked years ago, but I wanted to take a moment and share what I had done to resolve my issue.

#### **My Application Environment**

- OS: *Ubuntu 18.04 (AWS C9)*
- Rails *Version: 5.2.4*
- Ruby Version: *2.6.1*
- Database: *PostgreSQL 10.12*
- [Active Job Queuing Backend](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/active_job_basics.html#backends): *[Sidekiq 6.0.2](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq)*
- Additional Gems for Sidekiq

  - *[Sidekiq-Scheduler 3.0.0](https://github.com/Moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler)*

#### **My Issue**

To give you background and some perspective, I wanted create an interactive 3D globe that would help visualize application usage geographically. In order to achieve that I knew I would need to enable the geolocation feature of Ahoy. My initial plan was just to visualize it by country, so I was only trying to get the country in which the visit originated from. What I had soon discovered is that I had two issues....

1. **Ahoy wasn't showing any data in the following fields:**

   - Country *(Data Type: String)*
   - Region *(Data Type: String)*
   - City *(Data Type: String)*
2. **I was missing the following geolocation related fields in the database. They were not showing up in the schema.rb**

   - Latitude *(Data Type: Float)*
   - Longitude *(Data Type: Float)*

To help educate those that might be new to ruby on rails, here is a list of steps I took to initially identify the issue and also troubleshoot it after making changes:

Open a rails console.

```
rails c
```

Query the database (ActiveRecord) for an Ahoy visit record.

```
Ahoy::Visit.first
```

Returns the following hash. *(Some values in the hash below were replaced with "....." for obvious privacy concerns)*

```
 => #<Ahoy::Visit id: 1, visit_token: "687e8c98-1466-4adc-9224-15b4f8df18be", visitor_token: "819f2a25-a8ce-4f7b-a19b-07181e1fcc53", user_id: 1, ip: ".....", user_agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWeb...", referrer: ".....", referring_domain: ".....", landing_page: ".....", browser: "Chrome", os: "Windows", device_type: "Desktop", country: nil, region: nil, city: nil, utm_source: nil, utm_medium: nil, utm_term: nil, utm_content: nil, utm_campaign: nil, app_version: nil, os_version: nil, platform: nil, started_at: "2019-06-24 15:32:33", latitude: nil, longitude: nil>
```

#### **Resolving My Issue**

First thing I did was create a migration to add the missing `latitude` and `longitude` columns to the database (*Not sure why they were missing*). [Creating Ruby on Rails Migrations](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html).

```
rails generate migration AddLatitudeAndLongitudeToAhoyVisits latitude:float longitude:float
```

Now with the migration created, I ran the following to update the database:

```
rails db:migrate
```

Next I needed to discover why the geolocation data wasn't getting populated. Ultimately it ended up being that I had configured 3 queues for *Sidekiq* inside of the configuration file `\..\config\sidekiq.yml` used for the `Sidekiq-Scheduler` gem I listed above. Here is what I had configured:

```
:schedule:
  Acknowledged Notification Deletions:
    cron: '0 * * * *'   # Runs every hour
    class: NotificationsCleanupJob
    description: "This job runs every hour cleaning up all notifications that have been acknowledged by users." 

  Certificate Renewal Notfications:
    cron: '0 0 1 * *'   # Runs on the first of every month at midnight.
    class: CertificateRenewalNotificationJob
    description: "This job checks the renewal status of user certs and sends an email notification when expiration is within 30 days." 

:concurrency: 30
:dynamic: true
:queues:
  - critical
  - default
  - low
```

Reading back through the [Sidekiq Documentation](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy#geocoding), I found that the default queue for Ahoy is `ahoy`, makes sense to me. So at this point I had two options.

1. I could change the default queue for Ahoy and use the already created queue `low` *(see sidekiq-scheduler config above)*. I would simply need to add `Ahoy.job_queue = :low` inside of the configuration file for `Sidekiq`, located here > `\..\config\intializers\ahoy.rb`.
2. Or I could leave the Ahoy default queue of `ahoy` and just add it as a configured queue inside the `Sidekiq-Scheduler` configuration file `\..\config\sidekiq.yml`, under the `:queues:` section at the bottom. So it would look like this:

```
:schedule:
  Acknowledged Notification Deletions:
    cron: '0 * * * *'   # Runs every hour
    class: NotificationsCleanupJob
    description: "This job runs every hour cleaning up all notifications that have been acknowledged by users." 

  Certificate Renewal Notfications:
    cron: '0 0 1 * *'   # Runs on the first of every month at midnight.
    class: CertificateRenewalNotificationJob
    description: "This job checks the renewal status of user certs and sends an email notification when expiration is within 30 days." 

:concurrency: 30
:dynamic: true
:queues:
  - critical
  - default
  - low
  - ahoy
```

I ended up going with option 2. After implementing the changes I restarted both the application and the `Sidekiq` instance. While watching the `Sidekiq` instance terminal I revisited the application and immediately started seeing the following jobs kick off for Ahoy:

```
2020-04-20T15:23:46.733Z 4520 TID-gmuxo38gc Ahoy::GeocodeV2Job JID-1e053ab2e237431d0cfcb9b2 INFO: start
2020-04-20T15:23:46.796Z 4520 TID-gmuxo38gc Ahoy::GeocodeV2Job JID-1e053ab2e237431d0cfcb9b2 INFO: done: 0.062 sec
```

After that I verified that I was in fact seeing the geolocation data in the database, I decided to create some code to run in the the rails console to update all of the previous visits that don't currently have geodata. In my case there was only about 700 visits *(~30 seconds to update)*, so I wasn't worried about trying to chew more that I could swallow.
You can modify as needed if you have a large number of visits that need updated. Just copy and paste into a rails console and run it.:

```
#- Gather all visits with nil longitude, this should suffice.
visits = Ahoy::Visit.where(:longitude => nil)

#- Iterate over each visit in visits and queue the GeocodeJob to get the geodata
#- and update the record.
visits.each do |visit|
    #- This job actually queues another job called GeocodeV2Job that does the actual lookup.
    Ahoy::GeocodeJob.perform_now(visit)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable geocoding, add this line to your application’s Gemfile:

```rb
gem "geocoder"
```

And update `config/initializers/ahoy.rb`:

```rb
Ahoy.geocode = true
```

Geocoding is performed in a background job so it doesn’t slow down web requests. The default job queue is `:ahoy`. Change this with:

```rb
Ahoy.job_queue = :low_priority
```

Restart rails server:

```bash
$ rails s
```

Run the background service:

```bash
$ sidekiq
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77256288/16917889) is some more detail.