# Ahoy visits not created with after_validation :geocode uncommented

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ahoy

I have integrated Ahoy into our platform and it works great for tracking events etc. I am now trying to extend the functionality with enabling geocoding. The issue I am running into is as soon as I uncomment the

```
after_validation :geocode
```

line, visits stop recording in the database.

What am I doing wrong here?

### visit.rb

```
class Ahoy::Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "ahoy_visits"
  # ahoy_visit

  geocoded_by :ip
  # after_validation :geocode
  has_many :events, class_name: "Ahoy::Event"
  belongs_to :user
end
```

### ahoy.rb (note the short visit duration for testing):

```
class Ahoy::Store < Ahoy::DatabaseStore
end

# set to true for JavaScript tracking
Ahoy.api = true

# better user agent parsing
Ahoy.user_agent_parser = :device_detector

Ahoy.geocode = true
# Ahoy.server_side_visits = :when_needed

Ahoy.visit_duration = 10.seconds
# Ahoy.visit_duration = Rails.application.secrets.visit_duration

Ahoy.quiet = false
```

### geocoder.rb

```
Geocoder.configure(
    # Geocoding options
    timeout: 15, # geocoding service timeout (secs)
    lookup: :google, # name of geocoding service (symbol)
    :ip_lookup => :maxmind, # IP address geocoding service (see below for supported options):
    language: :en, # ISO-639 language code
    use_https: true, # use HTTPS for lookup requests? (if supported)
    # http_proxy: nil,            # HTTP proxy server (user:pass@host:port)
    # https_proxy: nil,           # HTTPS proxy server (user:pass@host:port)
    api_key: Rails.application.secrets.google_server_api_key, # API key for geocoding service
    # cache: nil,                 # cache object (must respond to #[], #[]=, and #keys)
    # cache_prefix: 'geocoder:',  # prefix (string) to use for all cache keys

    # Exceptions that should not be rescued by default
    # (if you want to implement custom error handling);
    # supports SocketError and Timeout::Error
    # always_raise: [],

    # Calculation options
    units: :km, # :km for kilometers or :mi for miles
    # distances: :linear          # :spherical or :linear
  )
```

To re-iterate, when I comment out the geocoding line visits are recorded properly and ahoy works as expected.
Thanks.

**EDIT**
I am certain there is an exception being thrown but it is not bubbling up in the logs and I have debug logging enabled. Ahoy just states that "[ahoy] Event excluded since visit not created:" yet on the UI we can see that a visit is being started via these log statements from ahoy:

> Visit started
>
> ahoy.self-01ef77de70801670c1f7f2f12fea979d59ba70488a77db75270b57ec5b1a2f8e.js?body=1:175
>   {visit_token: "4c7e0bcb-7afb-48cd-91ed-1bdf0d614767", visitor_token:
>   "374bf981-d843-45c3-953d-0f0b8fd5a6a7", platform: "Web", landing_page:
>   "http://localhost:3000/", screen_width: 1680, …}
>
> ahoy.self-01ef77de70801670c1f7f2f12fea979d59ba70488a77db75270b57ec5b1a2f8e.js?body=1:175
>   {name: "$click", properties: {…}, time: 1533656941.084, id:
>   "c967b67f-96f7-4f18-a9a8-df3735fdc1c2", js: true}

Comment: do you have the latitude and longitude attributes in your model?

Comment: No, just the default Ahoy models

Comment: if you see at the documentation of geocoder gem
`With ActiveRecord, add two attributes/columns (of type float or decimal) called latitude and longitude` try creating them and test it, if it works I will create the answer

Comment: It did not work, visits are still not being created. Thanks though

Comment: Hey @gwnp, did you manage to fix this, I am also running into a similar issue, i am however checking it on localhost

Comment: @opensource-developer unfortunately I didn't, we are running without geocoding enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and here are the steps to follow.

#### 1. Remove extra lines from `ahoy.rb`

There's no need to include `geocoded_by :ip` and `after_validation :geocode` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy/issues/4#issuecomment-39656892). Instead, simply set the following in config/initializers/ahoy.rb:

```rb
Ahoy.geocode = true
```

#### 2. Geocoding in Development/Test Environments

In development and test environments the local machine's IP looks like `127.0.0.1` or `::1` which aren't valid IP addresses for geolocation tracking. Try providing a custom IP address for debugging purposes. Add the following code at the end of your config/environments/development.rb:

```rb
class ActionController::Request
  def remote_ip
    # Write any IP address you'd like here.
    "71.212.123.5" # city: Seattle, region: Washington, country: US
  end
end
```

#### 3. Check if Sidekiq server is running

Geocoding is performed as a background job to avoid slowing down web requests. The default job queue for Ahoy is `:ahoy`. You can set the background job queue in config/initializers/ahoy.rb like this:

```rb
Ahoy.job_queue = :default # Ahoy suggests `:low_priority`, default is for quick debugging.
```

and run in the terminal:

```bash
$ sidekiq
```

#### 4. Verify Geocoding Service Configuration

Check that the Google API key and the lookup method are correctly configured and have the necessary permissions and subscriptions for geocoding. Google's geocoding service provides detailed responses, including error messages.  You can capture and log the response to check what might be going wrong.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77249267/16917889) might be useful for more details.